# How do I migrate my EeePC 901 from Xandros to Ubuntu 10.10 netbook remix?

Tags: ubuntu, netbook, usb-storage, xandros

I want to migrate my EeePC 901 from Xandros to the Ubuntu 10.10 netbook remix. I made a bootable USB key according to http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download, and the EeePC BIOS says it will boot from removable devices first, but when it boots it always boots from hard drive, never from the USB key.

Any ideas what I might be missing? Any workarounds if what I'm doing should work?

Comment: Can you try and boot another PC from the USB key to verify it's working OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press "Esc" key during boot you'll be shown a boot device selection menu

Comment: Thank you; I'm in the process of installation now. This was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

With the USB drive plugged in, press F2 when system boots and change the boot order and add the usb drive as the 1st boot device.

Comment: I did that before I posted; any other steps?